# Problems in Waking Mars 12.04-1 64bit

Tags: games

The Game Waking Mars is great however once you get mid way thru the game you get to an area where there is a large oval shaped stone that is supposed to be emitting a signal, a dialogue takes place between npc and yourself, your then supposed to use some sort of software to scan for the signal..  at this point the screen becomes solid colours with LARGE coloured circles in the background and the mouse cursor becomes an X/Y coordinate cross graph.

You can hear the game in the background but can do nothing any more to interact with anything.  The only thing at this point is to hard boot your PC as nothing else works.....  I've already put into 2 requests for help from TigerStyle and have yet to receive a response.

Comment: Why was this Downvoted? This question looks absolutely good to me... as well as interesting considering the answer posted by @rocketpanda ;)

Comment: @Aditya People may have thought it was game strategy advice and thus possibly off-topic ([related](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5750/22949)) or an attempt to report a bug in the game ([definitely off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, while this *turns out* to be the normal behavior of the game, the question itself assumed it was a problem, and others may assume that as well. I recommend against closing this question.

Comment: BTW, it did turn out to be a game-strategy-advice. Isn't it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Haha that's what's supposed to happen; it's not a glitch. It did take me a little while to get the right spot, but you have to move the mouse around until the picture is clear.